# intersectsNode fails when object goes counterclockwise but not clockwise

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, intersection

I am creating a very simple wheel game. There is no physics involved. a dial spins around a coloured quadrated wheel and must stop the dial on the correct colour. If they stop on the correct colour the dial spins the opposite direction with a new colour for them to match. I am using "intersectsNode" on a boundary line to detect when the dial enters a quadrant of the wheel and check if its the right colour etc. When the dial is spinning counterclockwise the dial correctly intersects with boundary lines when it touches them. However when the dial is spinning clockwise the intersectsNode is fired a third of the way before it even connects.

The same code is used to detect for both counterclockwise and clockwise and for creating the boundary lines, so I am confused as why it would fail one way vs. the other. Does anyone have any ideas? a bug perhaps that I am not aware of? a glaring issue with my setup?

[image]

```
@implementation GameScene {

    Sound *sound;
    GameModel *gameModel;

    SKSpriteNode  *wheel, *pin;
    float duration;

    Direction currentDirection;
    int colorCount;
    Color currentColor, startingColor, enteringColor;
    SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    gameModel = [GameModel sharedManager];

    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];

    wheel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wheel"];
    [self addChild:wheel];
    //wheel.zRotation = SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-45);

    SKSpriteNode *hub = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"hub"];
    [wheel addChild:hub];

    pin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blue_pin"];
    pin.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    pin.size = pin.texture.size;
    //pin.zRotation = SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45);
    [self addChild:pin];

    [self createBoundaryLines];

    PushButton *hubButton = [[PushButton alloc] initWithUpImage:@"blank_button" andDownImage:@"blank_button"];
    [hubButton setTouchUpInsideTarget:self action:@selector(switchDirection) parent:self];
    hubButton.zPosition = 50;
    [wheel addChild:hubButton];

    [self createScoreLabel];

    [self createResetButton];

    [self resetGame];
}

- (void)setScore:(int)score {

    _score = score;

    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _score];
}

- (void)createBoundaryLines {

    //counterclockwise lines
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"counterLine" color:[SKColor blueColor] position:CGPointMake(0, wheel.size.height / 2) size:CGSizeMake(1, 150) value:0]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"counterLine" color:[SKColor yellowColor] position:CGPointMake(wheel.size.width / 2, 0) size:CGSizeMake(150, 1) value:1]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"counterLine" color:[SKColor greenColor] position:CGPointMake(0, -wheel.size.height / 2) size:CGSizeMake(1, 150) value:2]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"counterLine" color:[SKColor redColor] position:CGPointMake(-wheel.size.width / 2, 0) size:CGSizeMake(150, 1) value:3]];

    //clockwise lines
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"clockwiseLine" color:[SKColor yellowColor] position:CGPointMake(1, wheel.size.height / 2) size:CGSizeMake(1, 150) value:1]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"clockwiseLine" color:[SKColor greenColor] position:CGPointMake(wheel.size.width / 2, 1) size:CGSizeMake(150, 1) value:2]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"clockwiseLine" color:[SKColor orangeColor] position:CGPointMake(1, -wheel.size.height / 2) size:CGSizeMake(1, 150) value:3]];
    [wheel addChild:[self createLine:@"clockwiseLine" color:[SKColor blueColor] position:CGPointMake(-wheel.size.width / 2, 1) size:CGSizeMake(150, 1) value:0]];
}

- (SKSpriteNode *)createLine:(NSString *)name color:(SKColor *)color position:(CGPoint)position size:(CGSize)size value:(int)value {

    SKSpriteNode *line = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:color size:size];
    line.position = position;
    line.name = name;
    line.userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [line.userData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"color"];
    line.zPosition = 500;

    return line;
}

#pragma mark - game methods

- (Color)getRandomColorButNotThisColor:(Color)color {

    //recursive method to find unique color other than one currently assigned
    Color randomColor = (int)arc4random_uniform(colorCount);

    if (randomColor == color)
        //same color so try again
        return [self getRandomColorButNotThisColor:color];

    return randomColor;
}

- (void)switchDirection {

    [pin removeAllActions];

    //if they are stopping the pin then it is either going to be correct or game over
    if (enteringColor != currentColor) {

        RLog(@"game over");
        return;
    }

    self.score += 1;

    //find a new color for them to match
    startingColor = currentColor;
    currentColor = [self getRandomColorButNotThisColor:currentColor];
    [self changePinToColor:currentColor];

    //change direction of the spinning pin
    currentDirection = (currentDirection == COUNTERCLOCKWISE) ? CLOCKWISE : COUNTERCLOCKWISE;
    [pin runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:2 * M_PI * currentDirection duration:duration]];
}

- (void)resetGame {

    [pin removeAllActions];

    pin.zRotation = 0;

    //reset all variables
    currentColor = startingColor = BLUE;
    [self changePinToColor:currentColor];

    self.score = 0;
    colorCount = 4;
    duration = 5.0;
    currentDirection = COUNTERCLOCKWISE;
    //pin.zRotation = SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45);
}

- (void)changePinToColor:(Color)color {

    //change the pin color based on the color that they need to match
    SKTexture *pinTexture;

    switch (color) {

        case BLUE:
            pinTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_pin"];
            break;

        case YELLOW:
            pinTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"yellow_pin"];
            break;

        case GREEN:
            pinTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"green_pin"];
            break;

        case RED:
            pinTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"orange_pin"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    pin.texture = pinTexture;
}

#pragma mark - game loop methods

- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    [self checkForCollisions];
}

- (void)checkForCollisions{

    if (currentDirection == COUNTERCLOCKWISE) {

        [wheel enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"counterLine" usingBlock:^(SKNode *line, BOOL *stop) {

            if ([pin intersectsNode:line]) {

                int amount = [line.userData[@"color"] intValue];

                [line runAction:[gameModel flashRedAction]];

                if (amount != enteringColor) {

                    enteringColor = amount;

                    RLog(@"entered %@", amount == 0 ? @"blue" : amount == 1 ? @"yellow" : amount == 2 ? @"green" : @"red" );

                    if (amount == currentColor - 1 || ((currentColor == 0) && amount == colorCount - 1))
                        RLog(@"game over!");

                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }
        }];
    }
    else {

        [wheel enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"clockwiseLine" usingBlock:^(SKNode *line, BOOL *stop) {

            if ([pin intersectsNode:line]) {

                int amount = [line.userData[@"color"] intValue];

                [line runAction:[gameModel flashRedAction]];

                if (amount != enteringColor) {

                    enteringColor = amount;

                    RLog(@"entered %@", amount == 0 ? @"blue" : amount == 1 ? @"yellow" : amount == 2 ? @"green" : @"red" );

                    if (amount == currentColor + 1 || ((currentColor == colorCount - 1) && amount == 0))
                        RLog(@"game over!");

                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

[image: gif showing problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `intersectsNode` documentation,

> two nodes are considered to intersect if their frames intersect.

A node's frame (i.e., bounding box) is a

> a rectangle in the parent’s coordinate system that contains the content of the node...

By observing the resulting bounding box as the pin rotates (see video clip), it becomes clear why using `intersectsNode` is not a reliable way to determine the pin's position within the wheel.

[image]

Alternatively, you can determine the pin's position directly from its `zRotation` property by

```
// Make sure angle in [-2pi, 2pi]. It can be a very large number
CGFloat angle = fmod(sprite.zRotation+M_PI_2, 2*M_PI);
// Make sure angle is positive and in [0, 2pi]
angle = angle < 0 ? angle + M_PI*2 : angle;
// Determine which quadrant the pin is in. An integer in [0, 3]
int quadrant =  (int)floor(angle/M_PI_2);
```

At this point, 'quadrant` indicates the color position of the pin, where 0 = yellow, 1 = blue, 2 = orange, 3 = green.

Comment: This is what I had initially thought and was convinced it was something like this. However it doesn't explain why it works correctly one direction and not the other. I have edited my post and added a animated gif that shows the pin going in both directions and the boundary lines flash when the pin connects with it.

I will look at your code and see if it will by pass this issue

Thanks for your help